# How to call a postgresql function that uses refcursors with node-postgres?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, node-postgres

I have a function that returns multiple result sets using `refcursor`. To give you an idea, here is how it is done:

```
   CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION showcars(ref1 refcursor, ref2 refcursor) RETURNS SETOF refcursor AS $$                        
    BEGIN
      OPEN ref1 FOR SELECT model FROM cars WHERE manufacturer = 'Ford';   -- Open the first cursor
      RETURN NEXT ref1;                                                                              -- Return the cursor to the caller
 
      OPEN ref2 FOR SELECT sold FROM sales WHERE manufacturer = 'Ford';   -- Open the second cursor
      RETURN NEXT ref2;                                                                              -- Return the cursor to the caller
    END;
    $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I call the above function like this to get the multiple results back:

```
BEGIN;

SELECT showcars(_ref1 := 'CarModels', _ref2 := 'CarSales');

FETCH ALL IN "CarModels";
FETCH ALL IN "CarSales";
COMMIT;
```

As you can see I pass the cursor name as a parameter, so the caller always knows which cursor to fetch. How do I run this from `node-postgres` to get the results back?

Comment: I would split into two functions, each defined as `returns table()` way easier to work with. And the small overhead of calling one more function isn't really that important

Comment: Does that mean there is no way to call it in its current format from node-postgres?

Comment: No idea (it is possible in Java/JDBC). But it's most probably easier if you use two functions and use two `select * from function()`

Comment: To elaborate a bit more my example was oversimplified. This one function powers a report so it actually calls about 10 other functions and returns all the results. Would you still say it was fine for the website to call 10 separate functions (or more) repeatedly many times?